# Wp-login appears White Screen, Error: Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, theme-development, login, wp-login-form

Possibly duplicate of many Question, the reason I am posting here none of them helps, here is the log which appear on Wp-login.php page.

```
Notice: automatic_feed_links is deprecated since version 3.0! Use add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' ) instead. in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2871

Notice: wp_deregister_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php:2871) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-login.php on line 384

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php:2871) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-login.php on line 396

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php:2871) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 678

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php:2871) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 679

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php:2871) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 680

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php:2871) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 875
```

**I am getting same thing on WP version 3.6 and WP version 3.7.1**

Now Here is what I have already did to make it work:

1. Disabling plugin from FTP
2. Switching theme by renaming the selected theme folder
3. Checking for Space after and before,
4. Replacing WP files with fresh download

**One more thing is this website developed on Windows Server and now Moving on Linux Server.**

Comment: Fix the `Notice`s first. The messages tell you what the problems are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now Here is what I have already did to make it work:
>
> 1. Disabling plugin from FTP

Which plugin?

> 1. Switching theme by renaming the selected theme folder
> 2. Checking for Space after and before,

After and before what?

> 1. Replacing WP files with fresh download

You stopped too soon. PHP is telling you what problems are occurring and you seem to be ignoring the notices and warnings it is giving you.

Let's read the first *Notice*:

```
Notice: automatic_feed_links is deprecated since version 3.0! Use add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' ) instead.
```

Now let's wrap the line and add some explanatory text to make it easier to read:

Problem:  The `automatic_feed_links()` function is deprecated since version 3.0.

Solution: Use `add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );` instead.

1. Look through the theme and plugin files for a call to the `automatic_feed_links()` function.
2. Start with the functions.php theme file.
3. Comment out that function call: `// automatic_feed_links()`. (It may not look exactly like this.)
4. Add a new line below that line.
5. On the new line add: `add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );`
6. Test the change to see if the Notice for that problem goes away.

---

Let's read the second *Notice*:

```
Notice: wp_deregister_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/truckgua/public_html/test2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012
```

Now let's wrap the line and add some explanatory text to make it easier to read:

Problem: The `wp_deregister_script()` function was called using the wrong hook.

Solution: Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts` hooks.

1. Look through the theme and plugin files for a call to the `wp_deregister_script()` function.
2. Start with the functions.php theme file.
3. Once you find the line with the `wp_deregister_script()` function call on it look for the name of the user defined function that line is located in.
4. Now, look for the `add_action()` function call that points to the user defined function.
5. Comment out that line as you did above.
6. Add a new line below that line.
7. On the new line add: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_name of the user defined function' );`.
8. Replace `the_name of the user defined function` with the name of the function you found in user defined function you found in step 3.
9. Test the change to see if the Notice for that problem goes away.
10. If the Notice remains, replace 'wp_enqueue_scripts' with 'admin_enqueue_scripts' in step 7 and repeat steps 8 and 9.
11. If the Notice remains, replace 'admin_enqueue_scripts' with 'login_enqueue_scripts' in step 7 and repeat steps 8 and 9.

Once the all Notices are gone, there will no longer be anything added before the headers and the other *Warnings* may go away.

---

These changes may not fix the page. Other errors may be doing that, but the Notices should be fixed first, before continuing with more debugging.

Comment: I did that, now the first 2 notice are gone, but the "Header Already Sent" Problem is still there, Wp-Login loads with empty response and warning after login form submit.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, here are answer to the question you asked for: 

1. I have Disabled all plugins, by renaming the plugins folder.

2. Space after and before <?php and ?> tags.

Comment: You can safely remove the closing `?>` PHP tag at the bottom of all files, but you do not need to do that now. Can you give us a link to your Login page so we can see the problem? If not look at the browser page source and see if there are any PHP warnings, notices or errors there that cannot be seen on the page. Sometimes the warning or notice is covered up by an image or by text.

Comment: I did this on my function.php, worked fine. There was one more thing I did, I am explaining it in your answer. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a theme that is relatively old and it is not compatible with the best practices of wordpres 3.4 and above.

The "deprecated" notices need to be fixed. One way is to actually fix them as @Charles suggested, and the other is to hide them by going to your config.php file and remove or comment the line where WP_DEBUG is set to TRUE.